# Don't know how to code, but I want to limit the number of tweets on my Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Can someone help me please? I've looked everywhere for help. I have a Wordpress site. I used Twitter instructions to create a live feed to my website to show my tweets. I copied and pasted this code into a text widget.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/JeffreyBuskey" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @JeffreyBuskey</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/JeffreyBuskey">Tweets by JeffreyBuskey
    src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I got my follow button and the live feed. However, the default, 20 tweets is out of control. I want to limit it to 5. Can someone tell me or show me what code I need to insert to limit my tweet to five. I found this: data-tweet-limit="3", but I don't know where to place it with the proper formatting/coding.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-tweet-limit="5"` parameter in your second `href`

secondly you missed opening `<script>` tag i added it,

add this code:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/JeffreyBuskey" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">Follow @JeffreyBuskey</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/JeffreyBuskey" data-tweet-limit="5">Tweets by JeffreyBuskey
    <script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: It will work perfectly and you will not loose your **follow button**, i am sorry i was putting parameter in first while it should be in second href  :)